# Micronaut is not considering defaultConfigurationId in management endpoints

Tags: java, micronaut

I am using micronaut 3 and I have currently `endpoints.all.path: /admin` in my properties. This is my endpoint controller:

```
@Endpoint(id = "userdetails", defaultConfigurationId = "booking", defaultSensitive = false)
public class AffiliateController {
    @Inject
    AffiliateAuthService authService;

    @Read
    public Publisher<? extends HttpResponse> getUserDetails(HttpRequest<?> httpRequest) {
        return Flowable.fromCallable(() -> {
            // Return user details
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
    }
}
```

I have mentioned `booking` as defaultConfigurationId here, and in properties I have added `endpoints.booking.path: /admin/bookings`.

But my controller method is not accessible by `/admin/bookings/userdetails`, it is only accessible by `/admin/userdetails`. Seems like this `defaultConfigurationId`  property does not override the existing "all" property. I cannot change `all` endpoint configuration because it is used by other endpoints. So how do I access my controller method by this route `/admin/bookings/userdetails` ?